# Bind a progress bar value with the value of a property given by an API

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I want to update the value of a progress bar in a WPF form to indicate the progress of a set of tasks.

The tasks are performed by an API provided in a dll. The API provides information about the total number of tasks and the number of tasks completed.

I have binded the value of the progress bar with a property in my main class, but I cannot display the progress during the execution of the tasks, just the progress at 0% and at 100%.

**MyForm.xaml.cs**

```cs
   public partial class MyForm : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public int PercentageOfTasksCompleted
      {
         get
         {
            int percentage_completed = 100 * externalAPI.NumberOfTasksCompleted / externalAPI.TotalNumberOfTasks;

            return percentage_completed;
         }
         set
         {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PercentageOfTasksCompleted"));
            }
         }
      }

      private async void ButtonExecuteTasks_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         await Task.Run(() =>
         {
            externalAPI.ExecuteTasks();
         });
      }
   }
```

**MyForm.xaml**

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="20" Width="200">
    <ProgressBar x:Name="myProgressBar" Value="{Binding PercentageOfTasksCompleted, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myProgressBar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

As for reproducing the scenario I think that the external API class could look like this:

**ExternalAPI.cs**

```cs
   public class ExternalAPI
   {
      public int TotalNumberOfTasks {get; private set;}
      public int NumberOfTasksCompleted {get; private set;}

      public void ExecuteTasks() {
         for (int i=1; i<=TotalNumberOfTasks; i++)
         {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            NumberOfTasksCompleted = i;
         }
      }
   }
```

What would be the best approach to have the progress bar value updated during the execution of the tasks? Thanks!

Comment: Is this Xamarin or WPF? You wrote "Xamarin" in your question, but tagged is as WPF. Where do you set the `PercentageOfTasksCompleted` property? Does Xamarin require you to explicitly handle the cross-thread marshaling for bound properties? Other XAML-based APIs don't (WPF, UWP), but maybe Xamarin does. At the moment, your question is of insufficient quality for a good answer to be provided. Please improve it, including by adding a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho it is WPF sorry, I have corrected the text. I do not know where to set the `PercentageOfTasksCompleted`. The only information that I get from the API is `TotalNumberOfTasks` and `NumberOfTasksCompleted`. Once I call `externalAPI.ExecuteTasks()` the only way for me to know the progress it to check `externalAPI.NumberOfTasksCompleted`. As for the minimal working example I think it can be:

`public void ExecuteTasks() {
  for (int i=1; i<=TotalNumberOfTasks; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    NumberOfTasksCompleted = i;
  }
}`

Comment: _"Once I call externalAPI.ExecuteTasks() the only way for me to know the progress it to check externalAPI.NumberOfTasksCompleted"_ -- then you will have to do that periodically while the task executes.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed get and set as follows:

**MyForm.xaml.cs**

```cs
   public partial class MyForm : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      private int _percentage_completed = 0;
      public int PercentageOfTasksCompleted
      {
         get
         {
            return _percentage_completed;
         }
         set
         {
            _percentage_completed = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PercentageOfTasksCompleted"));
            }
         }
      }
```

to set the PercentageOfTasksCompleted value:

```cs
while (externalAPI.NumberOfTasksCompleted < externalAPI.TotalNumberOfTasks)
{
   PercentageOfTasksCompleted = 100 * externalAPI.NumberOfTasksCompleted / externalAPI.TotalNumberOfTasks;
   Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

With this solution the progress bar value is updated at the specified intervals, but I wonder if there is a more "seamless" approach.

Answer (score 0):

so what u see is an inattention to variable types.
lets say you have 10 task totally .when the completed tasks are below 10 you always get zero(0),why? because you dividing two integers.and when it reaches 10, you get a 100%.
you simply need to cast one integer to a float number and then cast back to integer,its also a good practice to use `var` for variable definition:

```
    var percentage_completed = 100 * (int)((float )externalAPI.NumberOfTasksCompleted / externalAPI.TotalNumberOfTasks);
```

Comment: The issue was related to setting the variable percentage_completed so it could trigger the progress bar refresh. The conversion between types is performed as expected, since externalAPI.NumberOfTasksCompleted is multiplied by 100 before dividing by externalAPI.TotalNumberOfTasks. In your solution, the division is performed first because of the way you have grouped the operations, this leads to 0 being an operand until the divident and the divisor are equal, in which case it becomes 1.